# Getting error while value is link

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error.

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

**Table Structure:**

[image]

```
name ='fb' value='https://www.facebook.com/mypage'
```

**Model:**

```
function get_fb_url(){
    $query=$this->db->select('value');
    $query=$this->db->from('preferences');
    $query=$this->db->where('name','fb');
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data['fb_url']=$this->Home_model->get_fb_url()->value;
```

**View:**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $fb_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="css/imgs/fb.png" /></a></li>
```

When i run my page it give me error

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

only when if `value` in the table is link like above, if its simple text then text properly show on page.

**How Can i get rid off this error?**

Comment: it should be `$fb_url` in view while printing ??

Comment: @DharaParmar its typing mistake, i update my question.

Comment: `get_fb_url` is returning object array not object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo` use `return` type

Change

```
echo $this->db->get()->row();
```

to

```
return $this->db->get()->row();
```

And add `$` before variable name in view

```
<a href="<?php echo $fb_url;?>"
```

**UPDATED**

Change your model code to

```
function get_fb_url() {
    $this->db->select('value');
    $this->db->from('preferences');
    $this->db->where('name', 'fb');
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

Comment: oh sorry these are type mistake,  i update my question.

Comment: @stay yes like this `<li><a href="<?php echo $fb_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="css/imgs/fb.png" /></a></li>`

Comment: Pass $data as `$this->load->view('your_view',$data);` form your controller to view!!

Answer (score 0):

you must try like this:

```
function get_fb_url() {
       $this->db->select('value');
       $this->db->from('preferences');
       $this->db->where('name', 'fb');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query->row();
}
```

and in Controller:

```
$result = $this->Home_model->get_fb_url();
//try print $result, it must be an stdObject
$data['fb_url']=$result->value;
```

it is because in `$data['fb_url']=$this->Home_model->get_fb_url()->value;` `/` differentiate the link to the other function, that's why u r getting this error.

Comment: what is output ? have you try printing `$result` ??

Comment: use `print_r($result); die();` and check the result ?? use this after `model function call`

Comment: okk then double check your table, and see that is there any data in the table which contains `name` `fb` ??

Answer (score 0):

get_fb_url is returning object array not object. so you have to return value from method.

```
function get_fb_url()
{
    $query=$this->db->select('value');
    $query=$this->db->from('preferences');
    $query=$this->db->where('name','fb');
    return $this->db->get()->row()->value;
}
```

and than 
`$data['fb_url']=$this->Home_model->get_fb_url();`

Comment: it's probably because of `/`

Answer (score 0):

**In Your model do this**

```
public function get_fb_url() {
  $this->db->select('value');
  $this->db->from('preferences');
  $this->db->where('name','fb');
  $query = $this->db->get(); 
  $row = $query->row();
  return $row;
```

}

**In Controller :**

```
 $data = array();
 $result = $this->Home_model->get_fb_url();
 $data['fb_url'] = $result->value;
 $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

**In View :**

```
 echo $fb_url;
```